# CSS / JavaScript: How do I hide the vertical scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use jQuery to handle the scroling, so I want to get rid of the browser's scroll bar... how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well with css you could do that -> `overflow:hidden` on the body tag but you will not be able to scroll down anymore if the page is larger then the browser screen (unless you use your keyboard arrows)

Comment: Should we really be removing the users controls?  I thought this was considered bad practice in the same way that pop-ups are.  You will only disorientate the user. The user should be able to scroll if they want? Am I not correct?

Comment: You are totaly right, i wanted to make a note about it but i had to leave. Removing the scrollbar indeed removes the usability of the website and it is not recommended

Comment: well, I'm handling overflowing content differently, in a way, I feel is more intuitive (and lazier)

Comment: If you immediately don't get the results you seek, try adding it also to the html tag. ie:  html, body {height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS: `overflow:hidden;` will disable the scroll-bars of the element.

Not certain whether it will work on the whole page (ie at the body level), but you can always wrap your content in a div and style that.

Answer (score 2):

The way to prevent the browser scroll bar using jQuery is to keep your document height less than your window height. Meaning you would need a wrapping div and make sure your content never exceeds the window height.

```
$(document).height();
$(window).height();
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish though.

as others have suggested you can use the CSS property

```
body{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The actual use case would need to be presented to find which way would be best.

Comment: that's not really necessary, he just wants it to be hidden. it can be done with css, see my answer. I tested it out on this site using firebug

Answer (score 0):

For finer control over which scrollbar to show and hide you can also use overflow-x and overflow-y. Browser support is a bit tricky. You can check it with [this testcase](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) if there is a solution for only get rid of the vertical scrollbar in your case.

Comment: let's not make this to complicated, this not usefull at all

Comment: Since the question is specific about the *vertical* scrollbar, this makes it just complicated enough.